# inject dependency or declare dependency Tags : 1) ionic

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

There is great confusion wheater injecting depending  or declare it in constructor function.
here is the example

```
 import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
 import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
 constructor(private element: ElementRef, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document) {

  }
```

Now why Document is injectable and ElementRef is not.

please make me understable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`DOCUMENT` is a **constant** provided by the [`@angular/common`](https://angular.io/api/common) package ([API Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT)) to access the DOM.

**Note**: Document might not be available in the Application Context when Application and Rendering Contexts are not the same (e.g. when running the application in a Web Worker).

`ElementRef` is just a **class**, provided by the [`@angular/core`](https://angular.io/api/core) package, which you can use to access **Elements** in the DOM ([API Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef)).

An ElementRef is backed by a render-specific element. In the browser, this is usually a DOM element.

Because `ElementRef` is a **class** you have to create a new Object to use it.
Lets say you have a DIV with the id `myElementID` that you want to access:

*Angular 9 Example*

```js
@ViewChild("myElementID") 
private myElement: ElementRef;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because of a very simple reason, Angular needs to know what to inject. there are multiple ways to provide injections in Angular. the most common is providing by class. You are asking Angular which class instance you need, and it retrieves it for you. In your case
`ElementRef` is a class type, so DI knows what you are looking for. On the second Argument, there is no type for `_document` field, so how Angular should know what to inject ( it could inject anything on earth because it has default type Object), so you have to say somehow to Angular what to inject, and you are doing this bypassing token inside by `@Inject` decorator, that will help Angular to resolve an instance, like `DOCUMENT` token in your case.

you could imagine injecting by class, just a shorthand for `@Inject` decorator injection

```
(private elementRef:ElementRef) ==> (@Inject(ElementRef) private elementRef)
```